# SQL Server run SELECT for each in list

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I won't be surprised if SQL just doesn't work this way at all, but:

If we run two SELECT statements in a query, we get a split "Results" pane. I'm wondering if I can add variables to a list, and then have the number of result pane splits match the length of that list.

If I were to mix languages:

```
id_list = [26275, 54374, 84567]
for i in id_list:
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = i
```

I'm just trying to easily compare results of a query while keeping distinct groups, with a changing number of variables. Since loops never seem to be the answer in SQL, I'd be just as happy inserting something like a blank line or horizontal rule, etc. Not sure if that's possible either though...

Comment: You actually can use loops in MSSQL scripts, but to loop over an arbitrary list like that you'd need to declare a table variable with the values in your list, declare and open a cursor over that table, and then loop over the cursor results to execute the query for each one. If your real list is longer than that, it might be worth it, but for a few items and a simple query, you're better off just repeating the query. ...and if the list is too long, Sql server can start behaving unpredictably if there are too many result sets from such a script.

Comment: * you can use loops in MSSQL scripts through SQL Server Management Studio, I am not sure how they would function over a client application's connection if that is the intended path to the server; at that point, I usually just make a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of "lists" (as a separate data structure) in T-SQL.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (26275, 54374, 84567);
```

Comment: Really I'm just trying to separate results for convenient comparison. Your code would work if I could ORDER BY id and then have some separation inserted between each set by id.

Comment: It's not exactly a separator, but you could add a field like this `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 1 THEN CAST(id AS nvarchar) + '--->' ELSE '' END AS firstRecord` as a first column to emphasize the start of each id's results.

Comment: @yaxxor you mean visual separation? You can worry about that in your application's presentation layer surely. SQL is for getting the data. You can worry about what it looks like at a later stage. If this is just a one off, then dump it out to excel or something for further analysis

Comment: @ADyson Yes I definitely agree with you, and that's what I would normally try but I don't think it would work here. Basically I've already made my Excel export and I'm using SSMS to spot check the data behind potential duplicates. Each of those Excel rows has many corresponding historical rows in the db, and I'm checking hundreds per day. But also my post is just a question of convenience and working around it isn't so bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i int = 0;
declare @Id int;
declare @Ids table (Id int);
insert @Ids select Id from (values (26275), (54374), (84567)) t(Id);
-- OR: insert @Ids select * from string_split('26275, 54374, 84567', ',');
declare @Count int = (select count(*) from @Ids);

while @i <  @Count
begin   
    select @Id = Id, @i = @i + 1 
    from @Ids order by Id 
    offset @i rows fetch next 1 rows only;

    select * from dbo.MyTable where Id = @Id;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 26275
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 54374
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 84567
```